# Real time chars using highcharts, JSON, REST and Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, json, spring, spring-mvc, highcharts

I am writing a web application to gather real time data from database(Oracle database) to plot a chart using `Highcharts.js` library.

I am using `Spring 3.0` framework to fetch the data from database.

I want the charts to be updated after every 5 seconds.

So this is what I have decided till now:

Spring will fetch the data --> convert to JSON object --> send the JSON object to browser via REST services --> client side `Highchart.js` will plot the data on the chart

I have written the spring mvc part which fetches data from the database but I am clueless about how to work with `REST` services and Highcharts.

After looking online I found something called `@RequestBody` and `@ResponseBody` but no proper tutorial on how to use these.

Could someone guide me with some good examples to attain my objective?

This is the code currently:

**AdminController**

```
package com.rtc.controller;

import java.util.Random;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;


@Controller
public class AdminController {

    @RequestMapping("/chart")
    public String navigateToCharts(){

        System.out.println("redirecting to real time charts");
        return "rtc";
    }

    @Async
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String generateData(){

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        Random random = new Random();
        // sends a random value, which I will later replace from DB
        int value = random.nextInt(10);
        try {
            jsonObject.put("data", value);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("value sent is ="+value);
        return jsonObject.toString();
    }

}
```

**rtc.jsp** (the page where i want to display my highchart)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="js/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script>
function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getData.obj',
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(point) {
            var series = chart.series[0],
                shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is 
                                                 // longer than 20

            // add the point
            chart.series[0].addPoint(point, true, shift);

            // call it again after one second
            setTimeout(requestData, 2000);    
        },
        cache: false
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'rtcChart',
            defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
            events: {
                load: requestData
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Live random data'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 150,
            maxZoom: 20 * 1000
        },
        yAxis: {
            minPadding: 0.2,
            maxPadding: 0.2,
            title: {
                text: 'Value',
                margin: 80
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Random data',
            data: []
        }]
    });        
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <div id="text">The chart demonstrates the RTC</div>
        <div id="rtcChart"></div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

---

The code runs but just Prints "The chart demonstrates the RTC".

It never calls the function "getData".

Comment: I think you simply forget to include jQuery. Do it before highcharts.js file.

Answer (score 1):

@RequestBody annotated parameters for access to the HTTP request body. Parameter values are converted to the declared method argument type using HttpMessageConverters.

The @RequestBody method parameter annotation indicates that a method parameter should be bound to the value of the HTTP request body.

```
Example :

 @RequestMapping(value = "/projects", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 @ResponseBody
 public ProjectDetails createNewProject(@Valid @RequestBody ProjectVO projectVO) throws IOException {
        return projectManagerService.createNewProject(projectVO);
 }

 For the above rest service

Rest URl : /projects
Method : POST
Request body : ProjectVO
Response body : ProjectDetails
```

Comment: Thanks, I wrote some code based on your example. I have edited the question. The page loads but the charts don't load